# Ending sentence with 'Only'

Tags: adverbs

Can sentences end with 'only'? If yes, then in what cases you can or cannot?
For example

P2: I have had some problems but overall XYZ has been great.

P1: No, XYZ is a great product

P2: You misunderstood me. I was saying that only. / I was saying only that.

Comment: To really be able to answer, we'd need to know what each participant's *previous* sentence was. As it stands it's hard to discern your actual intent.

Comment: P2: I have had some problems but overall XYZ has been great. P1: No, XYZ is a great product. P2: You misunderstood me. I was saying that only.

Answer (score 1):

Some well-used examples:

- You are my one and only.
- For your eyes only.

It also works well where emphasis is required - "The equipment is for the use of club members only" or, any variation on members/staff/residents etc

Answer (score 0):

P1. No, XYZ is only a great product. No, XYZ is a great product only.

P2. I was saying only that. I was saying that only.

P3. The club is only for members. The club is for members only.

Yes,you can use the word only at the end of a sentence to give extra emphasis to the word or word phrase that it applies to.